# Printer not working on Void Linux

Tags: printer, void-linux, hplip, hp-printer

I have installed [Void linux](https://voidlinux.org/) which is otherwise working very well. It certainly is a smooth and stable distribution with a great package manager (xbps) which does dependency resolution also. The packages in repository (e.g. LibreOffice) are fairly recent.

However, I have not been able to make my Void Linux installation work with my HP Laserjet M1136 MFP printer/scanner. I have installed `hplip` and `cups`. I have tried to install it using command `sudo hp-setup -i` and also using `localhost:631` on browser. The printer is recognized but on there is always 'Filter failed' error on trying to print.

This printer/scanner works well with a Debian Stable Linux installation on a separate partition of same desktop computer. I found that there is a package called `hplip-data` installed on Debian but this package is not present in Void Linux repository.

What could be the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: `/etc/printers.conf` file is shown below:

```
NextPrinterId 12
<Printer HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1136_MFP>
PrinterId 11
UUID urn:uuid:64208fbb-c084-36f7-6ffd-55aa73ae7885
Info HP LaserJet Professional M1136 MFP
Location rnhome
MakeModel HP LaserJet Professional m1136 MFP hpijs, 3.20.9
DeviceURI hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1136_MFP?serial=000000000QHBV1CYPR1a
State Idle
StateTime 1617539017
ConfigTime 1617539027
Type 8425484
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

Edit: Printer started working after I used `hp-plugin -i` command. It downloaded required plugin and installed it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question if very vague. Have you checked https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_Pro_M1132_MFP ? At least show your `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I cannot find the link to download the driver. Also my printer is M1136 and not M1132, but they could have a common driver, as on this page: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-m1136-multifunction-printer-series/5094778/model/4075451 (only exe file here)

Comment: I have added `/etc/printers.conf` file contents in my question above.